# Reloading of SplitView in iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

how to reload splitView after login window??

I'm using SplitView based Application.

Comment: What do you mean by "reload"? If you want to reload one of the subviews, you must tell the subview controllers to do so.

Comment: In my application , i have simple login screen. After login, splitView appears on screen by adding splitviewController on the window as a subView. Till now everything works fine , i'm also able to navigate through different screens But whenever i tried to LogIN as User2  after loging out as User1. It still Shows the data of User1.
I know that this happens because i'm unable to reload Splitview. 
So can anyOne help me, how to reload splitview??

Answer (score 0):

If your data you want to reload is in a tableView, just reload the data in your tableView by

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Hope this helps.