# How to reload splitview after second logIn?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

In my application , i have simple login screen. After login, splitView appears on screen by adding splitviewController on the window as a subView. Till now everything works fine , i'm also able to navigate through different screens But whenever i tried to LogIN as User2  after loging out as User1. It still Shows the data of User1.
I know that this happens because i'm unable to reload Splitview. 
So can anyOne help me, how to reload splitview??

Comment: You will need to show some code on how you create and populate the splitview for us to help you.

Comment: btw, repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313768/reloading-of-splitview-in-ipad

Comment: In appDelegate.m file i stored the  instances of windows and splitViewController in variables of LoginView Class As follows:

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    
    // Override point for customization after app launch.
    
   
 loginViewObject =[[LoginView alloc] init];
 loginViewObject.loginWindow=window;
 loginViewObject.loginViewController=splitViewController;
 
 detailViewController.detailViewWindow=window;
 detailViewController.detailUIViewController=splitViewController;
 
    [window addSubview:loginViewObject.view];  //Add the Login view to the window and display.
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    return YES;
}

Comment: Btw i'm new to app development , CAn you tel me how to add code for others in good manner?

Comment: You should edit your original post and paste the code there. Then, format it using the "101010" button (code sample button) in the editor. That will help improve readability of your code.

Comment: In any case, that still does not give the information on how your splitview is populated with data, so I still cant say how you can reload your data. That is, unless you consider releasing the current splitview contents and recreating them from the beginning after a successful login (which may be less efficient than necessary).

Answer (score 0):

on successful log in, you need to (re)set the datasource, remove the detail view, and reload the data on the tableview in the navigation controller. without seeing how you are pulling in the data, we cant really tell you exactly what code you need to call.